# Is it possible to get Enum Type from String in Swift?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to get `Enum` Type from `String`?

```
ex: let type1 = WSCLogin.self <-- OK
ex: let type2 = someFunction(typeString: "WSCLogin") -> WSCLogin.Type <-- issue
```

I can save "WSCLogin" as string in somewhere
and letter I want to use this string("WSCLogin") to implement WSCLogin.Type.
Is it possible?
does someone who can figure out `someFunction(typeString: "WSCLogin") -> WSCLogin.Type` function? 
thanks

```
enum WSCLogin: String {
    case mail
    case password
}
```

Comment: what do you have in `someFunction(typeString:)`?

Comment: @ staticVoidMan thanks, I don't have the someFunction(typeString:), I just look for someone who can figure it out or does the swift provides.

Comment: So... this function, takes a string (the name of the type) and returns it as a usable type?

Comment: `WSCLogin` is the enum that defines the cases `mail, password`. You cannot initialize an enum with the name of the enum (`WSCLogin`). That is not how/why enums are used. You can store either case (mail, password) and later regenerate your enum from this value.

Comment: You could check the other way around but I am not sure I see the point with such code, `"/(WSCLogin.self)" == "WSCLogin"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following enum constructor:

```
let x: WSCLogin? = WSCLogin(rawValue: String)
```

This will provide an optional variable with a value if the string is a valid raw value or nil if the rawValue is invalid

Comment: @jim thanks, but I want to get WSCLogin.Type from string.

Comment: So you need something like this? `let x = "mail".Type; print(x)` will give output `WSCLogin`. Please confirm this is what you want

Comment: I have to say your requirement is confusing

Comment: @jim thinks for replying

Answer (score 0):

```
// the type without a String
let type1 = WSCLogin.self

// the type with a String, without extension
let mail = WSCLogin(rawValue: "mail")
let type2 = type(of: mail)

// the type with a String, with extension
extension WSCLogin {
    var kind: WSCLogin.Type {
        return type(of: self)
    }
}
let type3 = WSCLogin(rawValue: "mail")?.kind
```

Because we're initializing `WSCLogin` through the `RawRepresentable` initializer we always get an `Optional` type back. You just need to unwrap this first.

---

Please notice that you cannot use `type` or `Type` as property name because in both ways you'd run into name clashes. With backticks like so

```
var `type`: WSCLogin.Type
```

you can force the naming but in that case you override the `type()` function you use in this computed property.